# Sinusoidal Wave over a Circle

Tags: plotting

A sinusoidal wave can be plotted in a two dimensions. Generally and simply :

```
y[x]=Sin[(2pi/lambda)x]
```

As it is being plotted, the horizontal axis (as a straight line) is `x`, and the lambda is the wave length after which the wave will be repeated. How can one reach to a sinusoidal wave over a circumference which is not a straight line; Moreover the division of the circumference by the `lambda` has to be an integer number. It means: `n=(2pi*r)/lambda`. Here `n` is the number of lambda (wave) on the circumference and must be an integer, also, `r` is the radii of the circle.

Comment: `PolarPlot[r + Sin[n theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: Thank you, however this plot is a bit different of which I expected but it is enough and ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since any 2D transformation that maps the sine function onto a circle will distort the functional form, I would suggest drawing the sine function perpendicularly to the 2D plane as follows:

```
frames = With[{m = 10, r = 1, h = .3},
   Table[
    Show[
     ParametricPlot3D[
      {r Cos[ϕ], r Sin[ϕ], h Sin[m ϕ - t]}, {ϕ, 0,
        2 Pi},
      PlotStyle -> Tube[.03],
      PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-h, h}}
      ],
     Graphics3D[{
       Opacity[.4],
       Polygon[2 {{-r, -r, 0}, {r, -r, 0}, {r, r, 0}, {-r, r, 0}}]
       }]
     ],
    {t, Pi/5, 2 Pi, Pi/5}]
   ];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: sine]

This is the least distorted form in which you can probably expect to display the function.

The animation is only added for fun, you can omit it by setting `t=0` and getting rid of the `Table` construct.

Comment: it is wonderful!

Comment: I like the fun part, merry x-mas,